# pipe stream obtained from popen not giving data as expected

Tags: c, linux, shell, stream, popen

I have a command (say `cmd`).Below the representative output from this in a linux shell.

```
output line 1
output line 2
.
.
Checkpoint 1
.
output line 20
output line 21
.
.
Checkpoint 2
Checkpoint 3
Checkpoint 4
.
.
Checkpoint 8
```

There is considerable time difference between appearance of `Checkpoint 2` & `Checkpoint 3` , `Checkpoint 3` & `Checkpoint 4` etc(around 2 secs each).

I used popen as below to execute same command and parse the output.

```
FILE *fp;
int status;
char path[65000];


fp = popen("cmd", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
/* Handle error */;


while(1) 
{    
    while (fgets(path, PATH_MAX, fp) != NULL) 
    {
        print("%s\n",path);

        if(!strncmp("Checkpoint",path,strlen("Checkpoint"))
           printf("Reached : %s ",path);

        if(!strncmp("Checkpoint 8",path,strlen("Checkpoint 8"))
            break;
    }

}

status = pclose(fp);
if (status == -1) {
    /* Error reported by pclose() */
} else {

}
```

But with the logs obtained from above program (which is printed by the print statements in the program) , the Checkpoint logs appear on the screen almost simultaneously.

So I cant see the time difference of about 2 secs between `Checkpoint 2` & `Checkpoint 3` , `Checkpoint 3` & `Checkpoint 4` etc and it is almost 0.

I really cant see what might be wrong in my code snippet which parses `cmd`  output.

Comment: Does `cmd` generate the data line-by-line as you expect if you run `cmd | cat`?  Or does it get batched?  Standard I/O behaves differently if standard output is a terminal compared to a pipe or a file.  Gut feel, that's your problem here.  You may have to make `cmd` flush its standard output more frequently.  It should be less of an issue if `cmd` is a shell script that has `echo` or `printf` statements, or other commands, generating the output.  But the `cmd | cat` technique will show you a lot.

Comment: I will check it with the `cmd|cat` technique as you mentioned , but need atleast 9-10 hours more as need to do that at work!

Comment: The C library buffers the output from the `printf()` calls by default, because there is no newline in it. Add a `fflush(stdout);` (before the second `if` clause in the loop) to ensure everything thus far buffered is actually output, too.